# PHP Route not defined laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Working on a job portal, so I arrived at a point where employers need to edit their posted jobs,On page load it gave me an error `Route [employers/job/save/Mw==] not defined`, please I need help my deadline is 3hours from now!

Here is my code:

Routes:

```
//Route for Employer's specified Job Editting -> To get ID as argv
Route::get('employers/job/edit/{id}', 'employerController@editJob');

//Route for Employer's to save specified Job  after Editting -> To get ID as argv
Route::post('/employers/job/save/{id}', [ 
    'as' => 'saveJob',
    'uses' => 'employerController@saveJob'
]);
```

View:

```
{{ Form::open(['action'=>'employers/job/save/'.base64_encode($jobData->id),'class'=>'full-job-form', 'id'=>'jobForm','role'=>'form']) }}
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <label class="sr-only" for="">Job Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
            name="job_title" placeholder="Job Title"
            value="{{ $jobData->job_title }}">
        <span class="help-block">Eg. Marketing Manager</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `employers/job/save/{id}` route has a `/` prefixed - maybe try removing that?

Comment: Oh, also I don't think you can form parameterised routes by specifying the whole thing - you do something like this (using your named route): `{{ Form::open(['route' => ['saveJob', base64_encode($jobData->id)], 'class' => 'form-group' /* etc. */])`

Comment: @alexrussell Have removed the prefix and the result is still the same thanks

Comment: I did that too but the result was still the same! @alexrussell

Comment: see my answer for details on how to use `Form::open()` correctly and a link to the docs to hopefully help you out further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using the `action` parameter for your `Form::open()` call. This expects the name for a controller method (e.g. `{{ Form::open(['action' => 'employerController@saveJob']) }}`. If you want to link to a pre-generated URL use the `url` parameter:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'employers/job/save/'.base64_encode($jobData->id)]) }}
```

That said, that's not the best practice, as, if you change your routing system, you now have to change all these hardcoded URLs. As such, you should rely on named routing or controller actions.

Now, your route is already named (`'as' => 'saveJob'`) so you should actually use the `route` parameter of `Form::open()`:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['saveJob', base64_encode($jobData->id)]]) }}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `action` parameter as you are currently trying to do (albeit erroneously):

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['employerController@saveJob', base64_encode($jobData->id)]]) }}
```

See [the docs on forms](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) for more information.

---

Also, as @TheShiftExchange says, its a bit odd to be using the base 64 encoded id, why not just use the raw id?

Comment: Thanks a lot have fixed the error now I have another issue

Comment: No problem - if it answered your question, you should mark it as the answer so others finding the question in the future know that it worked.